# ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed. Why can't I run this tool with ArcPy, but I can use it in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-license-manager, error-000824

I am receiving the following error when trying to execute arcpy.PolygonToLine_management using PythonWin.

ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (PolygonToLine).

I am trying to automate a short workflow, and I tested the PolygonToLine tool while operating within ArcGIS Desktop, and it worked perfectly. Is there a certain extension I need to checkout to run it with Python? At the moment I only import arcpy and os. I reviewed the ArcGIS documentation, and could not find reference to a specific extension to checkout. Normally, ESRI will show examples of extensions needed to run tools, such as
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D"), seen in this example; https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/extrude-between.htm

The line of code it trips up on is very simple:

```
for i in list:
    arcpy.PolygonToLine_management(i, i + "_pLine", "IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS")
```

The list refenced contains 1 string, that being a FeatureClass name, while I test the process.

Edit: The documentation for this tool says it only runs in ArcGIS Advanced. Yet, I only have Standard and it runs while in ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Do you have more than one ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro installed? Maybe Pythonwin is using the wrong python environment

Comment: About your edit, the link you provide for ArcGIS 10.3 shows that the tool runs at any license level if you have the 3D analyst extension.